# shortname for complex filter in org agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, filtering

I want to give a shortname to a regular filter I use for agenda.

To prepare some meeting, i have a list of task / note with tag. I filter tag in org-agenda and before the meeting, i use org-agenda filter to get note.

Filter is like TAG1|TAG2|TAG3 ...

I want to just type in filter meeting1-filter. Is-it possible ?

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to go is to write a [custom agenda view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html#Custom-Agenda-Views). You would need to modify the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` in your init file to add your custom agenda view. Something like this (untested - I'll try to do some testing and fix any problems, but please be forewarned):

```
(setq meeting1-custom-agenda-view '("M" tags "TAG1|TAG2|TAG3"))
(eval-after-load 'org-agenda
   (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands meeting1-custom-agenda-view))
```

You can invoke your custom agenda view with `C-c a M` (assuming that `C-c a` is the key that is bound to the agenda dispatcher, `org-agenda`,  as recommended in the doc).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want and I don't know why I don't think this way. Thanks @NickD